# HtmlProvider parses Fraction As DateTime

Tags: datetime, f#, fractions, fsharp.data.typeproviders

Using HtmlProvider to access a web-based table sometimes returns a fraction as a string (correct) and, at other times, returns a DateTime (incorrect).
What am I missing?

```
module Test = 

open FSharp.Data

let [<Literal>] url = "https://www.example.com/fractions"
type profile = HtmlProvider<url>    
let profile = profile.Load(url)

let [<Literal>] resultFile = @"C:\temp\data\Profile.csv" 

let CsvResult = 
    do
        use writer = new StreamWriter(resultFile, false)
        writer.WriteLine "\"Date\";\"Fraction\""
        for row in profile.Tables.Table1.Rows do
            "\"" + row.``Date``.ToString() + "\"" + ";" |> writer.Write
            "\"" + row.``Fraction``.ToString() + "\"" + ";" |> writer.WriteLine

        writer.Close

let csvResult = CsvResult
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing sample data I can't be 100% certain, but I'm guessing that it's parsing fractions as dates if the numbers involved would be valid dates in the culture you're using: e.g., `1/4` would be a valid date in any culture that uses `/` as a separator, and would be treated either as April 1st or as January 4th, depending on which parsing culture your system defaults to.

Other type providers in FSharp.Data (such as the CSV type provideryou could ) allow you to configure how each column will be parsed, but that's not an option the HTML type provider gives you. (Which is a bit of a missing feature, of course). But since the HTML type provider does allow you to specify the culture info for datetime and number parsing, one way you might be able to work around this is specify a culture that does *not* use `/` as a separator (but still uses `.` as a decimal point, since otherwise if the HTML you're parsing has numbers written like `1,000` for one thousand, that could be interpreted as `1`). One such culture is the `en-IN` culture ("English (India)"), where the date separator is `-` and the decimal point is `.`.

So try passing `Culture=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-IN")` in your `HtmlProvider` options, and see if that helps it stop treating fractions as dates.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. However, setting Culture="en-IN" did not work as I continue to experience the following types of error: for example, "05/09/2017 00:00:00" instead of "5/9".

Comment: Then you might have to use `HtmlParser` to extract the table data. Thankfully, it works pretty well alongside `HtmlProvider`: you can use `profile.Tables.Table1.Html` to get an `HtmlNode` data structure that represents the `<table>` element, then use `.CssSelect("tr")` to get a list of rows, and on each row you can use `.CssSelect("td") |> List.map HtmlNode.innerText` to get a list of strings. For more details, see the [`HtmlParser` documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlParser.html).

Comment: I do not wish to mix functional-like (HtmlProvider) and imperative-like (HtmlParser) code in the application, if possible. Right now, I alternate between the following options: 
 `["\"" + row.Fraction.Month.ToString() |> writer.Write `
 `"/" |> writer.Write `
 `row.Fraction.Day.ToString() + "\"" + ";" |> writer.Write] `
and 
 `["\"" + row.Fraction.ToString() + "\"" + ";" |> writer.Write] `
as required. Is there an idiomatic way of using both options in the same "for row" loop?

Comment: The HtmlParser code has an [`HtmlNode` module](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-htmlnodemodule.html) with a functional-like API for just about everything (except, for some reason, `.CssSelect`, which is a strange omission). But it's quite easy to write your own: `let cssSelect selector (node : HtmlNode) = node.CssSelect(selector)`, and then you can do `tableNode |> cssSelect "tr" |> List.map (cssSelect "td" >> List.map HtmlNode.innerText)`. This gets you a list of rows, where each row is a list of strings. All functional-like code, with nothing imperative-like at all.

Answer (score 0):

The following combination of functions worked:

```
// http://www.fssnip.net/29/title/Regular-expression-active-pattern
module Solution = 

   open System
   open System.Text.RegularExpressions

   open FSharp.Data

   let (|Regex|_|) pattern input =
      let m = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
      if m.Success then Some(List.tail [ for g in m.Groups -> g.Value ])
      else None

   let ptrnFraction = @"^([0-9]?[0-9]?)(\/)([0-9]?[0-9]?)$"
   let ptrnDateTime = @"(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})"

   let ToFraction input = 
      match input with
      | Regex ptrnFraction [ numerator; operator; denominator ] ->
        (numerator + operator + denominator).ToString()
      | Regex ptrnDateTime [ day; month; year; hours; minutes; seconds ] ->
        (day + "/" + month).ToString()
      | _ -> "Not valid!"

   let dtInput = @"05/09/2017 00:00:00"
   let frcInput = @"13/20"

   let outDate = ToFraction dtInput
   printfn "Out Date: %s" outDate

   let outFraction = ToFraction frcInput
   printfn "Out Fraction: %s" outFraction

   //Output:> Out Date: 05/09 Out Fraction: 13/20
```

Thus, I was able to replace:

```
"\"" + row.``Fraction``.ToString() + "\"" + ";" |> writer.WriteLine
```

with:

```
"\"" + ToFraction(row.``Fraction``.ToString()) + "\"" + ";" |> writer.Write
```

Thanks to @rmunn for the clarity of his explanations and the benefit of his expertise.